# Erroneous value for commit options in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a `submit_tag` form helper in one of my apps. The value of this submit button should change dynamically. The two possible values for this submit button are `Save` and `Update`. So, in the view, I have done something like the following:

```
<% temp = 0 %>
<% text = '' %>
<% temp =  ActivityLog.find_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM logs WHERE id > 0")%>
<% text = temp[0][:count].to_i > 0 ? 'Update' : 'Save' %>

<!-- other html contents -->

<%= submit_tag text, :id=>"submitBtn"+i.to_s, :onclick=>"submit_button_clicked(this)"%>
```

Now, when I run the view inside a browser, I can see the desired effect. But the rails controller receives the erroneous value for the `commit` options in the `params` hash.

For instance, when the value of `text` is evaluated to `Save`, I get the following in the Firebug:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" style="" onclick="submit_button_clicked(this)" name="commit" id="submitBtn3">
```

But `raise params.inspect` in the associated controller shows the follwing:

```
{"commit"=>"Update",
 "authenticity_token"=>"",
 "time"=>{"292"=>"3.0",
 "2"=>"1.0",
 "456"=>"4.0"},
 "date"=>"2011-09-20"}
```

See, although the value of the Submit button is shown as `Save` in the HTML, the rails controller shows the value of `commit` as `Update`. What's wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails helpers, it provides a simple way to choose text on button with according to type of form:

```
<%= form_for @activity do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>:
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When no value is given, it checks if the object is a new resource or not to create the proper label. In the example above, if @activity is a new record, it will use "Create Activity" as submit button label, otherwise, it uses "Update Activity".

P.S. please do not use SQL in your views

Comment: if you need to override default values, use **@activity_log.new_record?** to detect whether it **create** either **update**

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to submit a form by Ajax. So I've used `form_remote_tag` and the `submit_tag` is part of that asynchronous form. I need it to be Ajax, so I can't use `form_for` here. (and I'm maintaining some legacy code here and can't really figure out the way for not using the SQL in the view....but I'll try my best to move it outta here to the Controller.)

Comment: if you need to update button text, there is 2 ways: wrap button in a partial and check **new_record?**, the second way is to use ajax callback and update button' text with callback on client side

Comment: anyway, perform an sql query just to update a button text is not a good idea for your server side performance and overall application architecture design